# Im trying to upgrade from laravel 7 to laravel 9 but I get this error:

Tags: php, laravel

- macsidigital/laravel-api-client[3.3.0, ..., 3.3.4] require macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-client ^1.2 -> satisfiable by macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-clie
  nt[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.x-dev, v1.x-dev].

  - macsidigital/laravel-zoom[4.1.5, ..., 4.1.9] require macsidigital/laravel-api-client ^3.3 -> satisfiable by macsidigital/laravel-api-client[3.3.0, ..
    ., 3.3.5].
  - macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-client[1.2.0, ..., 1.2.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-
    dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
  - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0
    .0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev], laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
  - mcamara/laravel-localization v1.7.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.2.0||~5.3.0||~5.4.0||~5.5.0||~5.6.0||~5.7.0||~5.8.0||^6.0||^7.0||^8.0||^9.0 -> sati
    sfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
  - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v9.0.0-beta.1 (conflict analysis result)

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Comment: `macsidigital/laravel-oauth2-client` does not allow you to upgrade, you can see it is saying it requires `laravel/support 7 or 8`, you want `9`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like version 3.x of `macsidigital/laravel-api-client` has a dependency that doesn't support Laravel 9.

Try updating it to version 4.x first: `composer require macsidigital/laravel-api-client "^4"`